# Macro requires extra $ when it doesn't make sense

Tags: macros

I made this macro to help write the parallel resistor equivalence formula. Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{xparse,etoolbox,pgffor}
\newcommand{\parallelResist}[1]{
        % TODO: fix extra + appearing at begining
        % TODO: fix requiring $ around resistors when already in math mode
        \ensuremath{
            \frac{1}{
                \def\nextitem{+}% Separator
                \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{
                    \nextitem\frac{1}{\textsf{##1}}
                }
                \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, when using this command in math mode, I have to surround the arguments with $, like this:

```latex
\begin{equation}
    R_{eq} = \parallelResist{$R_1$, $R_2$, $R_3$}
\end{equation}
```

I would like to be able to use it without the $, like this:

```latex
\begin{equation}
    R_{eq} = \parallelResist{R_1, R_2, R_3}
\end{equation}
```

But this gives me an error: `Missing $ inserted.`

What is the thing in my macro causing this?

Comment: Does replacing  `\textsf` by `\mathsf` help? The trouble is that you want to wrap `\textsf{##1}` around `R_1`, and this obviously does not work because the underscore requires math mode.

Comment: Yes it does... What do those commands do?

Comment: Both make the text/content sans serif, `\textsf` in the text mode, and `\mathsf` in the math mode.